# Anonymous links wont open when clicked, only when copied and pasted into browser

Tags: sharepoint-online

Users are reporting that when an anonymous link is clicked on, they get the an "access denied" message or that they are "not part of this organization" type message. However if the url is copied and pasted into the browser it works fine.

What could be the issue here?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue. Does it happen on all users? How about other items?

Ensure **Limited-access user permission lockdown mode** site collection feature is disabled.

Clear the browser cache and ensure you have not signed in to the SharePoint site, compare the results. In addition, check it in another browser.

When clicking on the link, check the requests and responses using Fiddler.

Comment: Happens for a lot of users and it only seems to happen to PowerPoint files.

Limited-access user permission lockdown mode is disabled. 

Thanks for your reply